# how to set text to textfield android with one default value along with an additional value

Tags: android

I want to set text to textfield as Rs balance. Where Rs will be default and balance would be passed my a method. I'm using the follow code

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                //SELECT USERS BALANCE FROM TABLE
                int balance=db.balance(activeuser);
                t2.setText(String.valueOf(balance));

}
```

The above code only displays the value of the balance in the textfield. Help me to display Rs along with balance.

Comment: t2.setText("Rs"+String.valueOf(balance));

Comment: yeah it is working!

Comment: If its a EditText then you should use a `TextView` just left to it having `Rs` as text . Or if If a `TextView` then you can directly set `t2.setText("Rs"+String.valueOf(balance));`.

Comment: Got the answer. thanks @ADM